# Jquery click function for entire <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jquery click function that works when a div is clicked with a specific class:

```
$().ready(function () {
   $('div.clickableDiv').click(function () {
      //...do something
   });
});
```

This is what my 'clickableDiv's look like:
http://gyazo.com/7cce83f3241ae28068ec9256ffd8f44f

This jquery function works, but only when *content* inside the div is clicked, such as the text or image. Can I make this so If I click anywhere in the div (border/backgroud/content) it will work?

Right now the text can be highlighted and the image can be dragged around, is it possible to make it all one block (like the image and text acting like a background), so the block can be clicked rather than having to worry about where in the div is clicked?

```
HTML (made with PHP):
//<li> generates the box of data
Echo '<li>';
   //div contains all the data in the <li>
   Echo '<div id="itemDiv' . $i .'" class="clickableDiv" style="disply:block;">';

      //content in div
      //text
      //image
      //text

   Echo '</div>';
Echo '</li>';
```

Comment: that is a class not an id. Ids use # and classes use ..

Comment: Show your markup, please. There's almost nothing to go on here.

Comment: @isherwood There is a lot of HTML involved in it, I added what I believe could be necessary.

Comment: @MitchCool1 they want to see the rendered html not the code that generates it. copy from inspector

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way by surrounding you `a` tag

```
    <div class="clickContainer">

    <a class="download-tooltip" href="/downloading" target="_blank" data-reactid=".0.2"><span data-reactid=".0.2.0"><strong>This image</strong> was created and uploaded in less than 3 seconds.</span><br data-reactid=".0.2.1"><span data-reactid=".0.2.2">Get the fastest tool to share your screenshots. </span><div class="download-tooltip-btn" data-reactid=".0.2.3"><div class="btn btn-primary" data-reactid=".0.2.3.0">Download <strong>Gyazo</strong> for free</div></div></a>

    </div>
```

and the js

```
   $().ready(function () {
   $('div.clickContainer').click(function () {
  //...do something
   });
   });
```

Comment: I added my HTML to the question. The div is already doing what the <a> is doing, just surrounding what was already there. Would adding the <a> tag make any difference?

Comment: if you want the border and the margins clickable. click on the container. This is simple

Answer (score -1):

Make you div have `display:block`.

Changing the display fills thhe empty part of the div, allowing you to click.

Comment: I added it, hasn't seemed to have changed the result though. Updated the question with it too.

Comment: Divs are block by default.